# cannot create MongoDb client object! [Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found]

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I'm on macOS sierra.
I installed mongodb using brew and starting it using `$ mongod` command.
Also, the mongo shell works fine without any luck!
The problem is when i'm using this code to create a connection:

```
$mongoClient = new MongoDB\Client();
```

same for

```
 $mongoClient = new MongoClient();
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class ... not found in ...
```

The fun point is when i'm trying to use mongo driver manager it works!

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

I'm sure that i have `extension=mongo.so` in my php.ini file and i checked phpinfo() and that shows Mongodb is loaded, i can'f find a solution for fixing it!
whats the problem?

Comment: That's the "low level" dependency you have installed. It's a "prerequisite" but you **want** the [composer install for "userland" work.](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must properly [install the MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setup.php). With `phpinfo()` you can check if it is working.

Then [install PHP library for MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php).

Also you should do not forget that PHP-CLI and PHP-FPM/mod_php have separated configurations (the php.ini files)